# In R, How to retain the original format of dates when I load in a dataframe with a sequence of dates as its header?

Tags: r, dataframe, date, header

The dataframe I loaded in, `DF`, has a sequence of dates as its header. However, `"2020-02-01"` became `X2020.02.01` e.t.c. Is it possible to retain the format of the dates and name the columns by them? And how can I get a list of dates in the original format, i.e `["2020-02-01", ... , "2020-04-21"]`?

```r
DF = read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PawinData/UC/SFBA/Targets.csv")
```

Answer (score 2):

R doesn't like column names that are really data. Further, column names are always converted to `character`, so they won't be real `Date` objects. Either way, if you read [`?read.csv`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html), you'll see the `check.names=` argument.

> check.names: logical.  If 'TRUE' then the names of the variables in the
>   data frame are checked to ensure that they are syntactically
>   valid variable names.  If necessary they are adjusted (by
>   'make.names') so that they are, and also to ensure that there
>   are no duplicates.

```r
read.csv(text = "2020-02-02,2020-02-03\n1,2")
#   X2020.02.02 X2020.02.03
# 1           1           2
read.csv(text = "2020-02-02,2020-02-03\n1,2", check.names = FALSE)
#   2020-02-02 2020-02-03
# 1          1          2

DF = read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PawinData/UC/SFBA/Targets.csv", check.names = FALSE)
DF[1:3,1:5]
#                2020-02-01 2020-02-02 2020-02-03 2020-02-04
# 1      Alameda          0          0          0          0
# 2 Contra Costa          0          0          0          0
# 3        Marin          0          0          0          0
```

Though realize that you'll need to go a step further in some of your subsetting.

```r
DF$2020-04-21
# Error: unexpected numeric constant in "DF$2020"
# x
DF$"2020-04-21"
# [1] 28.719660 36.410103  3.961824 36.634331 17.015503 19.567608 12.449088
# [8]  2.419292 20.666366
DF$`2020-04-21`
# [1] 28.719660 36.410103  3.961824 36.634331 17.015503 19.567608 12.449088
# [8]  2.419292 20.666366
```

Names:

```r
colnames(DF) # or just names(DF)
#  [1] ""           "2020-02-01" "2020-02-02" "2020-02-03" "2020-02-04"
#  [6] "2020-02-05" "2020-02-06" "2020-02-07" "2020-02-08" "2020-02-09"
# [11] "2020-02-10" "2020-02-11" "2020-02-12" "2020-02-13" "2020-02-14"
# ...truncated...
```

Incidentally, your first column appears to have an empty name, as can be seen above and here:

```r
head(DF[[1]])
# [1] "Alameda"       "Contra Costa"  "Marin"         "Napa"         
# [5] "San Francisco" "San Mateo"
```

You can deal with that in two ways:

```r
### original read method:
DF = read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PawinData/UC/SFBA/Targets.csv", check.names = FALSE)
names(DF)[1]
# [1] ""
names(DF)[1] <- "counties"
DF[1:3, 1:5]
#       counties 2020-02-01 2020-02-02 2020-02-03 2020-02-04
# 1      Alameda          0          0          0          0
# 2 Contra Costa          0          0          0          0
# 3        Marin          0          0          0          0
```

or by making them R-proper "row names":

```r
DF = read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PawinData/UC/SFBA/Targets.csv", 
              check.names = FALSE, row.names = 1)
DF[1:3, 1:5]
#              2020-02-01 2020-02-02 2020-02-03 2020-02-04 2020-02-05
# Alameda               0          0          0          0          0
# Contra Costa          0          0          0          0          0
# Marin                 0          0          0          0          0
```

Admittedly, many packages (namely tidyverse) don't use or preserve row names. A common recommendation is to convert row names into a proper column, as the first example demonstrated.